# Loop through array from NIST API.. Cant get it working

Tags: php, arrays

Im working with some data from the NIST CVE Database.

Im putting it through the simpleXMLElement array but cant figure out how to loop through it properly.

Tried following other threads here but cant it working.. These miltidimensional? arrays break me.

Any help would be super great!

Here is the array dump:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (2) {
  ["channel"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (4) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(31) "National Vulnerability Database"
    ["link"]=>
    string(41) "https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search"
    ["description"]=>
    string(114) "This feed contains the most recent CVE cyber vulnerabilities published within the National Vulnerability Database."
    ["items"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#151 (0) {
    }
  }
  ["item"]=>
  array(148) {
    [0]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (3) {
      ["title"]=>
      string(35) "CVE-2008-6594 (rdf_newsfeed_export)"
      ["link"]=>
      string(62) "https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2008-6594"
      ["description"]=>
      string(150) "SQL injection vulnerability in the cm_rdfexport extension for TYPO3 allows remote attackers to execute arbitrary SQL commands via unspecified vectors."
    }
    [1]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (3) {
      ["title"]=>
      string(26) "CVE-2014-5129 (projectdox)"
      ["link"]=>
      string(62) "https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-5129"
      ["description"]=>
      string(162) "Cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerability in Avolve Software ProjectDox 8.1 allows remote attackers to inject arbitrary web script or HTML via unspecified vectors."
    }
    [2]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (3) {
      ["title"]=>
      string(24) "CVE-2019-9565 (antidote)"
      ["link"]=>
      string(62) "https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2019-9565"
      ["description"]=>
      string(467) "Druide Antidote RX, HD, 8 before 8.05.2287, 9 before 9.5.3937 and 10 before 10.1.2147 allows remote attackers to steal NTLM hashes or perform SMB relay attacks upon a direct launch of the product, or upon an indirect launch via an integration such as Chrome, Firefox, Word, Outlook, etc. This occurs because the product attempts to access a share with the PLUG-INS subdomain name; an attacker may be able to use Active Directory Domain Services to register that name."
    }
```

Im using this code but it just echos "item" each time..

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($apiData);
var_dump($xml);

$i="0";
foreach ($xml->item as $key => $value) {
        echo $xml['item']['$i']['link']; // get the CVE link..
        echo "KEY:$key Value:$value \r\n";
        $i ++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `->` notation for getting the link. The array index is what you called the key. So I would name that `$i`:

```
foreach ($xml->item as $i => $item) {
    $link = $item->link;
    echo "Index:$i Link:$link \r\n";
}
```

Comment: should be `$item->link` (missing $).  Can't edit as it would be too small a change

Comment: PERFECT! THANK YOU! - Will mark as correct answer when it lets me!